# How to verify a tar file in Windows?

Tags: windows, tar

In an effort to create more disk space I am trying to compress a bunch of my data into `.tar.gz` files. This takes a long time, so I'd like to automate the process in a `.bat` file. Ideally I would create the `.tar.gz` file, verify that it is a valid file, and then delete the uncompressed data from the server. **How do I verify that the new tar file is valid in Windows?** The Linux version of tar has the `-W` option which seems perfect, but that isn't included in the Windows version. I've been manually running `tar -t` and verifying that it didn't encounter any errors before deleting the original data, but I'm not sure how I'd use that in a script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, it's unlikely, unless you have a serious problem with your RAM or storage, that an archive that you just created is broken. What should have happened? `tar` and consorts are more-than-well-tested. Also, you're asking the same program running on the same machine that you suspect might produce broken files to check whether it did. Raises a lot of questions on your mental model of what could fail!

---

So, "it's taking a long time": Let's address that first.

When doing something like

```
tar czf compressed.tar.gz folder1/ folder2/
```

`tar` internally uses a single threaded version of the gzip compressor.

Not only is gzip not a very good compressor, it's also slow, and only using a single thread doesn't help, either.

You could achieve the same result, but much faster (assuming you have more than one CPU core, but even on a single core, this might be beneficial) through

```
tar czf - folder1/ folder2/ | pigz > compressed.tar.gz
```

You can get *better* (but slightly slower) gzip compression using

```
tar czf - folder1/ folder2/ | pigz --best > compressed.tar.gz
```

[`pigz`](https://zlib.net/pigz/) is just a multi-threaded gzip implementation.

But gzip (and thus also pigz) is a terrible compressor, as said, slow *and* inefficient. Use something that's not designed with 1980's PCs in mind, and you get much better speeds and/or rates. [Zstd](http://facebook.github.io/zstd/) is popular for backup compression. At a speed that should be very similar to that of gzip:

```
tar czf - folder1/ folder2/ | zstd -10 > compressed-roughly-as-fast-as-gzip.tar.zst
```

You'll notice that for most types of data, the result uses about 30% less space (very roughly, really depends on the data!).

And to compress roughly equally well, but much much faster

```
tar czf - folder1/ folder2/ | zstd -3 > compressed-roughly-as-good-as-gzip.tar.zst
```

Both `zstd` and `pigz` should be available the same way you've installed your `tar`.

> The Linux version of tar has the -W option which seems perfect, but that isn't included in the Windows version

Ah, your Linux version is probably GNU tar, whereas the "Window version" (whatever that is) probably is a different tar implementation (maybe the busybox or bsdtar version?).

---

> How do I verify that the new tar file is valid in Windows?

It's darn hard to make a **tar file invalid**. Basically, you can truncate it.

So, an easy way of checking whether the tar file is *valid* is to simply decompress it. Checking whether the **contents are intact** is a different problem, and can essentially only be solved by extracting it and comparing the files (that's what GNU tar does with `-W`, but it omits the writing to a file, does the comparison in RAM).

You don't have a GNU tar with the `-W` option, so you can then do something like (assuming bash):

```shell
# create compressed archive
original_folder="$(pwd)"
archivename="compressed.tar.zst"
tar xvf - original_files | zstd -12 > "${archivename}"

# Verify
## enable recursive globbing
setopt globstar
## make temporary directory
tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
cd "${tmpdir}"
## extract
tar xf "${original_folder}/${archivename}" || echo "Decompression failed"
## go through all files, hash' em
hashes="$(sha256sum --tag **/*)"
cd "${original_folder}"
echo "${hashes}" | sha256sum --check  || echo "hash verification failed"
## Clean up
rm -rf "${tmpdir}"
```

Comment: I suspect that tar _wasn't_ installed by OP – current releases of Windows 10/11 come with libarchive 3.5 "bsdtar" `tar.exe` in-box (which uses an internal zlib).